# Projective varieties: rational maps and morphisms of schemes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-varieties

I'm a beginner with algebraic varieties topics, and I studied a (very little) of scheme before. The fact is that I don't truly manage to correctly understand the bridge between the different notions of "morphism" I encountered. Actually, let $X$, $Y$ be a projective varieties, $X=\operatorname{Proj} (k[T_0, \dots, T_n]/I)$, where $I$ is an homogenous ideal and $k$ a field (algebraically closed if needed), and $Y=\operatorname{Proj}(k[T_0, \dots, T_n]/J)$, where $J$ is an homogenous ideal. There are two notions of morphisms $Y \to X$ I saw :

1. $X$ and $Y$ are schemes, and then we have the usual meaning of morphisms of schemes, and so a morphism $Y \to X$ is a $k$-morphism in the sense of schemes;
2. The point of view of rational map, so a morphism $Y \to X$ is an equivalence class of tuples $\phi=(\phi_0: \dots : \phi_n)$, $\phi_i \in \overline{k}(X)$, defined at $P$ for all $P \in Y$, and not all zero.

My question is, how to show that those two definitions coincide ?

Thank you!

Comment: Varieties are covered by affine charts $U\to U'\subset X,V\to V'\subset Y$, from there it suffices to know what is a morphism of affine varieties (a function $f:U\to V$ given by polynomials which correspond to rational functions on $X$ regular on $U'$ and such that $f(u)\in V$) and to know what is a gluing of charts and morphisms (for varieties it suffices to find that they coincide in the function sense on some open). This is really the algebraization of the notion of holomorphic maps on complex manifolds.

Comment: A formatting tip: \operatorname{Proj} will product the correct formatting and I've taken the liberty of updating your post with this.

Comment: @reuns There is something which is not clear to me. Following what you've said, and also what is written out on Wikipedia, when we look locally, we have : $f : U \to V$ given by $x \to (f_0(x) : \dots, f_m(x))$ where $f_i$ are homogenous polynomial of same degree (until here, it's okay). But, it's written then that it's also the case in $X$ by continuity. I don't figure why ? Why if the fact that it's the case locally implies it's the case on $X$ ?Why we could not have different polynomials for the differents charts, which coincide on the intersection of the given open set ?

Comment: Locally "near" $x_0$ your map is given by $x\to (u_0(x):\ldots:u_m(x))$ where the $u_j$ are rational functions $X\to \overline{k}$, regular at $x_0$, and one of them is $1$. If $X$ is a projective variety then the rational functions are quotients of homogeneous polynomials in $x$, let $g$ be the product of the denominators, then your morphism coincides with the rational map $x\to F(x)=(g(x) u_0(x):\ldots: g(x)u_m(x))$ on some open, where the $g(x)u_m(x)$ are homogeneous polynomials in $x$.

Comment: I say rational map because there might be some $x$ where $F(x)=0$ in which case $F$ might not be a morphism to $\Bbb{P}^m$ at those points.
Then the question is if we can extend $F$ to some of those points where $F(x)=0$ (if you are told that $F$ is a morphism then yes) by multiplying/dividing the $g(x)u_j(x)$ by another rational function or homogeneous polynomial. The rational map uniquely defines $F$, but even if $F$ extends to a morphism it is not obvious at all that there is a polynomial/rational expression for it making it defined on the whole of $X$

Comment: @reuns Thank you for all your explanations !